# Modal window slightly shifted on right side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to center a modal window into browser window (I am doing test on Firefox, Chrome and Opera).

You can test it by clicking on this [link](http://beulu.com/last/dev_debug/issue_with_modal_window/index_debug5.html) and after clicking one more time on image at the center: the modal window should appear (it is empty, I removed the components into this modal window).

To center the modal window into browser window, I did :

```
// Width and Height of WebGL window : 90% of browser window width
var mainWidth = 0.9*$(window).width();
// Height deduced from starting image : 490/900 is the ratio of starting image, so I keep proportions.
// image
var mainHeight = mainWidth*(490/900);
```

And after :

```
  // Padding and Margin
  var paddingLeft = parseInt($('.popup_block').css('paddingLeft'));
  var paddingTop = parseInt($('.popup_block').css('paddingTop'));
  var borderLeft = parseInt($('.popup_block').css('borderLeftWidth'));
  var borderTop = parseInt($('.popup_block').css('borderTopWidth'));


  // Compute x and y limits for pop up
  var xPop = ($(window).width() - (mainWidth + paddingLeft + borderLeft))/2;
  var yPop = ($(window).height() - (mainHeight + paddingTop + borderTop))/2;
```

Finally, I make appear modal window with :

```
// Make appear pop-up and add closing button
  $('#'+popID).fadeIn().css({'width': mainWidth, 'height': mainHeight, 'top': yPop, 'left': xPop}).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="./close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

  // Display background
  $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
  // Working only for background
  $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'contrast(0.8)'}).fadeIn();
```

with `'#'+popID` the `jQuery id` of modal window.

I need help about this slight shift on the right (empty space is larger on right side than on left side): did I forget another parameter (padding, margin, border ...) to take into account?

Comment: where is the css for `.popup_block`? can you give us a demo that replicates the problem?

Comment: try doubling the padding/border - `var xPop = ($(window).width() - (mainWidth + (paddingLeft * 2) + (borderLeft * 2)))/2;
  var yPop = ($(window).height() - (mainHeight + (paddingTop * 2) + (borderTop * 2)))/2;`

Comment: thanks, that does the trick . But just a question : why doubling padding/border ? regards

Comment: Is there any reason you're doing this in Javascript and not CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.popup_block` has full padding and borders all around, but you're only grabbing the left padding/border and top padding/border values and using that to absolutely position the element using `top` and `left` properties, so the element will actually display a little wide on the right/bottom sides since the right/bottom padding/border weren't accounted for when positioning the element.

Since the padding/border is uniform all around, you can just double the `paddingLeft, borderLeft, paddingTop, borderTop` values.

```
var xPop = ($(window).width() - (mainWidth + (paddingLeft * 2) + (borderLeft * 2)))/2;
var yPop = ($(window).height() - (mainHeight + (paddingTop * 2) + (borderTop * 2)))/2;
```